# Vaadin Designer support for Properties in Custom Components

Tags: vaadin

We're using Vaadin Designer with some simple customer Componets, such as:

```
public class SCheckBox extends CheckBox
```

with properties:

```
private String fieldName = "";

public String getFieldName()
{
    return fieldName;
}

public void setFieldName(final String pFieldName)
{
    fieldName = pFieldName;
}
```

Designer finds the components in our classpath and inserts the package-mapping into the .html so that we can insert them into the layout (manually - the custom components aren't placed onto the Palette tab), but the properties of these custom components aren't displayed on the Properties tab and when we set the value via text:

```
<sabe-s-check-box caption="_onlyShowProjectedStockouts" _id="onlyShowStockouts" field-name="onlyShowStockouts"></sabe-s-check-box>
```

the field-name attribute is removed when we round trip to the WYSIWYG mode and back to the text edit mode, however the properties belonging to the super ComboBox, such as caption, are not removed.

Are we missing an annotation on the property or some other magic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to close this: from Vaadin, the current Designer (1.0.6) does not support attributes on custom components.  It's on their todo.